# Can I use eclipse to create Android Apps?

Tags: android, eclipse

Can I use eclipse with java to create an Android app?  One programmer said yes, but a programmer at IBM said no. I'm tring to put app on the android market.

Is it possible to just use the Eclipse IDE to create an android app or do I need to use a different IDE?

Comment: While I see that the question is answered, a simple search of "android eclipse" told me everything I needed to know :>.

Comment: wow i guess im horrible at looking stuff up lol

Comment: It's ok - comment wasn't meant to be harsh. I will say this - Google search has taught me as much if not more than all my years of college :). Most of my Android skills were learned from Google (and some books / open source apps). Happy Googling!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create Android apps using Eclipse.  You'll have to install the Android SDK and ADT before you get started.  Here are some guides to get you started:

http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-eclipse.html

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_eclipse.html

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse is the most popular. There are options such as `IntelliJ IDEA,` `Netbeans`.

The followings

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/publish-to-android-market/ and

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

will be helpful on how to export your app to android market.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can Java is one of the most popular languages to program in for android creation.

Answer (score 1):

The [MoSync IDE](http://www.mosync.com/documentation/manualpages/eclipse-ide) is based on Eclipse and is conveniently cross-platform. You might consider that.

However, there's [a how-to for Android apps in Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) located at the Android Developer site.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use the Eclipse IDE for Android Development:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Answer (score 0):

While Eclipse is the most popular for developing Android applications, you can use other IDEs such as Netbeans and IntelliJ IDEA..

You can find more info at

http://www.nbandroid.org/ for Netbeans

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/google_android.html for IntelliJ IDEA

Personally I prefer Eclipse, but if you are uncomfortable using Eclipse you can use those IDEs.